# Why this two objects are equal (==)?

Tags: php, object, comparison

In PHP I have two objects, they are different because of the $_frets variable (x is a string "x"), but PHP says

```
($o1 == $o2) == TRUE.
```

Why?

Dump of `$o1`:

```
guitarChord Object
(
    [_guitarChord:guitarChord:private] => 
    [_chord:guitarChord:private] => chord Object()
    [_baseFret:guitarChord:private] => 0
    [_frets:guitarChord:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => x
        )

    [_tuning:guitarChord:private] => tuning Object()
    [currVariation] => 0
    [nextVariation] => 
    [prevVariation] => 
)
```

Dump of `$o2`:

```
guitarChord Object
(
    [_guitarChord:guitarChord:private] => 
    [_chord:guitarChord:private] => chord Object()
    [_baseFret:guitarChord:private] => 0
    [_frets:guitarChord:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 0
        )

    [_tuning:guitarChord:private] => tuning Object()
    [currVariation] => 0
    [nextVariation] => 
    [prevVariation] => 
)
```

EDIT:

So the reason why is because `("x" == 0) = TRUE`. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Probably not responsible for this problem, but why are you using `==` instead of `===`?

Comment: Because the `===` operator checks if the variables refer to the same instance of the same class, which is probably not what he's trying to do here.

Comment: You are correct. Those two are not equal because the arrays differ. So something else must be happening somewhere else in your code... Please provide a working code snippet that illustrates the behavior.

Comment: The thing is I'm printing_r and seeing the two objects different but right after print_r I do $a==$b and I get true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does x represent a string or does x represent null? If it represents null, then this is my theory: the [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) page has a transcription of the array comparison algorithm in Example #1.  Based on this, I would imagine that in your case, what would end up happening is a comparison between 0 and null.  According to the table above that, when null is compared to anything, it is converted to a bool.  So you end up comparing 0 (false) to null (false), resulting in the two arrays being considered equal.

Comment: Hey Man! you are right... if("x" == 0){ print "yes";} I'm getting YES! Try it

Comment: Ah yes... "x" is converted to a number, so if("x" == 0) becomes if (0 == 0)... so thank you. My solution will be convert all numbers to string so the comparison is made between strings and not between numbers and strings.